# Lawnchair query plugin - uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, lawnchair

I've just started using Lawnchair's Query plugin and I cannot seem to get the query syntax to work with a parametised argument in the where() clause.

```
var store = new Lawnchair('store', function() {
});

store.nuke();

// save some data
store.batch([{a:"abc"},{a:2},{a:2},{a:"def"},{a:4}], function() {

});

// query (works)
store.where("record.a === 2", function(results) {
    alert('got ' + results.length + ' results');
});

// query (works)
store.where("record.a === 'abc'", function(results) {
    alert('got ' + results.length + ' results');
});


// Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined
store.where("record.a === ?", 'abc', function(results) {
    alert('got ' + results.length + ' results');
});

// Works but does not return any results
store.where("record.a === ?", "'abc'", function(results) {
    alert('got ' + results.length + ' results');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx79D/1/)

I believe I'm doing this as per the [Lawnchair unit tests](http://brian.io/lawnchair/tests/test/plugin/query.html).